# rsyslog ignoring settings file

Tags: logging, fedora, rsyslog

changing the `/etc/rsyslog.conf` has no effect for my rsyslog.

After changing the settings I call `service rsyslog restart` and it starts up without any problems.

I for instance tried commenting out all rules but it keeps logging as before.
And every log message is logged to the mysql but the rule says it should only log the message from the remote host.

Here is my config file:

```
#### MODULES ####
$ModLoad ommysql
$ModLoad imjournal
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514

$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog

$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

$IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state
$IMJournalIgnorePreviousMessages on

#RULES
kern.*                                                  /dev/console
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log

 if ($fromhost-ip=='123.123.123.123') then :ommysql:localhost,log,log,password
 &stop
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason restarting rsyslog seems not reload all the settings, a reboot of the system solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the imfile module.  Changing the value for $InputFileStateFile solved this for me.  Seems rsyslogd might hold the state file contents in memory, and doesn't refresh them on a restart.

Rsyslogd 5.8.10